# Text Editor Dialog

Tags: python, python-2.7

im trying to learn how to use my text editor to open files, or atleast locate em at first. But i get this Error when i run(Using wxPython):
def OnOpen(self,e):
                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

```
import wx
import sys

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(500,300))

        self.Control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar()


        filemenu = wx.Menu()

        Open = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "Open", "Opens a file.")
        Save = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "Save", "Saves a file.")
        Close = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_CLOSE, "Close", "Close a file.")

        infomenu = wx.Menu()

        About = infomenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "About", "Info about the program.")
        infomenu.AppendSeparator()
        Exit = infomenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "Exit", "Exits the program!")

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        menuBar.Append(filemenu, "File")

        menuBar.Append(infomenu, "Info")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, Exit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, Open)



        self.Show(True)
    def OnExit(self, event):
        exit()
    def OnOpen(self,e):
        """ Open a file"""
        self.dirname = ''
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
            self.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, "Hrrs01's text editor")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I would add `wxPython` and `wxWidgets` to the questions tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've mixed tabs and spaces in the same file, but set the tab size to 4 cells. Use `python -tt` to confirm.